# Installing a program over again using terminal

Tags: installation, command-line

I've installed an application using `sudo apt-get install ...` in terminal. However, I forgot to `sudo apt-get update` before installation, so an old version of the application was downloaded and installed.

I did this procedure over again and the newest version was installed. Is this ok or will it cause problems? What happened to the old version? Was it simply overwritten?

Answer (score 1):

No problem at all. The old version was replaced with the new one. If you had `apt-get update` before install it would end up in the same state as it is now.